# Problems for create sequence in PostgreSQL and SpringBoot (JPA)

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa, spring-boot

I have a problem for create a sequence in PostgreSQL, I use a SpringBoot/Hibernate/JPA for this issue, When the application will create tables and sequences, Hibernate don´t use the **schema** property for @SequenceGenerator.

```
   @Entity
   @Table(schema=Schemas.ADMIN, name="tbl_client")
   public class Client implements CommonsEntity<Integer>{

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   static final String SQ_CLIENT = "sq_client";

   @Id
   @Column(name="id_client")
   @GeneratedValue(generator=Client.SQ_CLIENT, strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   @SequenceGenerator(schema=Schemas.ADMIN, name=Client.SQ_CLIENT    sequenceName=Client.SQ_CLIENT, initialValue=1, allocationSize=1)
   private Integer id;
```

The sequence created in Postgre is: **create sequence sq_client**

I use SpringBoot 1.3.5 and Hibernate 4.3.11.

Thanks.

Comment: I resolved using Hibernate version 5 and SpringBoot 1.4.X.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using incorrect strategy for GeneratedValue.

```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = SQ_CLIENT)
  @SequenceGenerator(name = SQ_CLIENT, sequenceName = SQ_CLIENT,
      allocationSize = 1,initialValue=1)
  private long id;
```